# filtering posts in flask / SQLalchemy by a date in a datetime column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building a website in Flask, and I need to find a way to filter the posts displayed on the page between past and current posts, based on the `end_date` column.
All the current posts would be on one list, and the expired posts would be on another list.

Here is the model

```py
class Events(db.Model):
    __tablename__="events"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False, unique = True)
    start_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default = datetime.utcnow)
    end_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False)
    body = db.Column(db.Text, nullable = False)
    form_link=db.Column(db.String(100), nullable = True)
    data_link=db.Column(db.String(100), nullable = True)
    slug = db.Column(db.String(20))
    bg_img = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable = False, server_default = '') #set a default bg img
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', lazy=True, backref="Posts")
    imgs = db.relationship('EventImgs', lazy=True, backref="pics", cascade="all, delete-orphan") 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not 'slug' in kwargs:
            kwargs['slug'] = slugify(kwargs.get('title'))
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self) :
        return f" Event{self.title}, {self.end_date} "
```

and here is the query I'm trying to use.

```py
todays_date = datetime.now
current = Events.query.filter(Events.end_date >= todays_date).all()
past = Events.query.filter(Events.end_date <= todays_date).all()
```

But I can't find the right way to get this query to work, either I get a blank set, or in the case of this post, I get the following error.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input.
[SQL: SELECT events.id AS events_id, events.title AS events_title, events.start_date AS events_start_date, events.end_date AS events_end_date, events.body AS events_body, events.form_link AS events_form_link, events.data_link AS events_data_link, events.slug AS events_slug, events.bg_img AS events_bg_img
FROM events
WHERE events.end_date >= ?]
[parameters: [immutabledict({})]]
```

What's the best way to get the queries to work properly?

Comment: This is the problem: `todays_date = datetime.now`. `datetime.now` is a method and needs to be called, i.e., `todays_date = datetime.now()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blank set returned means it could not fetch any records matching the query, do you get the records from db directly when using same query ?

For the second issue please update the code to use `datetime.now()` instead of `datetime.now`.